# Java how do i save a random item returned from a string array as a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, jlabel

Im relatively new to Java and cant seem to get a straight answer from my lecturer at college, so I apologise if this is a dumb question. I'm creating a level up screen for my assignment, and it needs to include an array.

I've created a string array called "randomTitle" containing a list of character titles, I need a button to pull a random title from my array list and display it on a JLabel on my level up screen, but am unsure how to save the random title returned as a variable in order to display it, can anyone help me?

```
Random ran = new Random();
String ary = randomTitle[ran.nextInt(randomTitle.length)];
titleJLabel.setText(String.valueOf(randomTitle));
```

Comment: *"but am unsure how to save the random title returned as a variable"* ... ask yourself what variable `ary` is, then you might know it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int random = (int) (Math.random()*randomTitle.length);
titleJLabel.setText(randomTitle[random]);
```

So through a slow process of elimination, this ended up solving my issue, I tried setting the JLabel to ary to begin with, which displayed my entire array, useful to know but not what I was aiming for. I've tested the programme over and over now and it seems to be working perfectly fine, Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're trying to set the JLabel to a random address in the string array randomTitle. You already have the answer, if that's your question. However, for some reason you seem to be setting the JLabel to String.valueOf(randomTitle). What you want to be doing is setting the JLabel to the random address, which you already have stored in ary. Try setting the JLabel to ary.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a one-liner using [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

```
titleJLabel.setText(randomTitle[Math.random().nextInt(randomTitle.length)]);
```